# fixing a regex pattern to be more precise

Tags: php, regex

```
alertsystem.notification = {"msgId":"1","msgTitle":"Message","msgBody":"No new message.","msgLink":"","msgImage":""};
```

I am trying to match the values for of the follow variables in the code above. I have been using this pattern `preg_match('#(\[\{.*?\}\])#s', $html, $match);` up until last week then it stopped working.

Is there a way to include `alertsystem.go =` in the pattern so that I am sure to get a match?

Comment: Is this JSON? If it is, have you considered cutting out the data part and `json_decode()` ing it?

Comment: Have you tried just including that new prefix in the regex?

Comment: For debugging regex I recommend you check out http://weitz.de/regex-coach/ which has some very nice features and works under Wine on Linux.

Comment: @Pekka `preg_match('#(\[\{.*?\}\])#s', $html, $match);
$values = json_decode($match[1], TRUE);` this is what i have but it doesn't give me the values for msgbody or msgtitle etc it gives me values for something completely different

Comment: @mario i'm not sure exactly how to add it in any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest reading the manual. `preg_match` is no black magic, and most static search strings can be added without difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `preg_match_all` and then take a look at `$matches[0]`. Your regex could also be: `#alertsystem\.notification\s*\=\s*\{.*?\}#is`

Add parenthesis where appropriate to capture specific sections.

Comment: I tried placing the `()` in various parts of the regex patter but i can only get it to return the entire string. where can i place it so that it only returns the values for `msgTitle":"Message","msgBody":"No new message.","msgLink":""`which are "Message", "No new message."and ""

Comment: instead of `{.*?\}` use `{(.*?)\}`. Then `var_dump($matches);` to see where the captured matches are. I can't remember and can't be bothered.... oh wait.. look.. okay: they'll be in $matches[1]. http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php